# Remove variable name from JSON data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a string of JSON to the client from a database for a JavaScript plugin to highlight the states it gets back. However, in addition to the state information I need, I'm also getting the variable name. Is there anyway I can correct the formatting so that instead of it looking like this:

```
{"statesHighilght":["California","Washington","Utah","Utah","Florida","Kansas","Utah"]}
```

I get this:

```
["California","Washington","Utah","Utah","Florida","Kansas","Utah"]
```

This is what my controller code looks like:

```
public ActionResult highlight()
{
    var statesHighlight =
        db.Jobs
            .Select(r => r.State);
    return Json(new { statesHighilght }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the enumerable directly to the `Json` method instead of wrapping it in an anonymous object.

`return Json(statesHighlight, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`